# Wordpress url re-write

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress plugin for searching car list. The url for the list of cars depend on the company make and id. it will appear like http://www.signaturecarleasing.co.uk/carsearch.php?a=man&man=1 for the alfa romeo car. I need to rewrite the url which could be similar to http://www.signaturecarleasing.co.uk/carsearch/alfa-romeo for alfa romeo. may I know how can I rewrite the url. The permalink change settings in wordpress and .htaccess file is not making any change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
RewriteRule ^carsearch/alfa-romeo$ /carsearch.php?a=man&man=1 [L]
```

then repeat for every $_GET['man'] value. But you'd better rewrite the code to accept manufacturer's name and not the numeric id.

p.s. has nothing to do with WP's permalinks

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply Michael. But unfortunately code didnt work out. It is coming in the same way as before. I did the changes in .htaccess file.

Comment: Can we do it in the carsearch plugin Michael?

Comment: They are not dofferent pages axtually. ]

Comment: They are not different pages actually. It is a file in the plugin called carsearch.php. So it search within the plugin itself. May I know is there any solution for the problem please?

Comment: sure you can do that in the plugin. you probably have to do it there.
whenever my rewrite rule works or not depends on many things and you should have some more understanding of how it works or be more specific with "didn't work". The solution is probably to spend sometime understanding first.

Comment: I tried the code 

$url = '';
if (!empty($_GET['man'])) {
    $url .= $_GET['man'] . '/';
} else {
    $url .= "alfa-romeo";
}
include $url;

in the page. My I know is this the way to rewrite the url please?

Comment: you do realize that to help you I need to read your "plugin" code? and then code the new code? That won't be the knowledge sharing that will be hiring a freelance.